# Setting multiple javabeans properties from a multiple select

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, multiple-select, struts-tags

I have an Action that is like

```
public class MyAction{
    private List<MyObject> objectList;
    //Public Getters and Setters
}
```

And `MyObject` being Like:

```
public class MyObject {
    private String propertyA;
    private String propertyB;
}
```

next, I have a Jsp with a `<s:select/>` mapped to the `objectList` list.

```xml
<s:select name = "objectList" 
          list = "objectList" 
       listKey = "propertyA" 
     listValue = "propertyB" 
         value = "%{objectList.{propertyA}}" />
```

But whenever I post my form to it returns an `input` result with the following message:

> Invalid field value for field "objectList"

What is the correct way of passing those values to the action, in order to set the correct properties of my List ?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the voodoo of using the same List as both source and target, and a list projection on it as a value (!), the error is:

You are listing `MyObject`, showing `propertyA` as value, and using `propertyB` as key.

But when you post the selection, you will post an array of `propertyB`, not an array of `MyObject`.

Then you should do like that:

```
@Getter         private List<MyObject> sourceObjectList;
        @Setter private List<String>   selectedObjectList;
```

```xml
<s:select name = "selectedObjectList" 
          list = "sourceObjectList" 
       listKey = "propertyA" 
     listValue = "propertyB" 
         value = "%{sourceObjectList.{propertyA}}" />
```

<sub>(The Lombok annotations are just to be more clear)</sub>

Comment: i'm on it. I used the same list only for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Ok but the problem was that, a list of objects instead of a list of strings